# Firebase Realtime Database listen to .childChanged at specific child path

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to get notified when a sub child of a child changed? For instance

```
posts
    post1
        text: ...
        comments: ...
        likes: 2
    post2
        text: ...
        comments: ...
        likes: 30
```

I want to get a post whenever its `likes` changed. I tried to use `root.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "likes").observe(.childChanged)` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase query listens to the data directly under the location where you attach the query. A `child...` listener fires for the child node immediately under the location where you attach the query.

There is no way to listen to only a specific property of each child. If you need that, you will have to create a separate branch in your JSON for just those properties. E.g.

```
posts
    post1
        text: ...
        comments: ...
        likes: 2
    post2
        text: ...
        comments: ...
        likes: 30
likeCounts
    post1: 2
    post2: 30
```

Now you can listen to just `/likeCounts` for the changes you want.